# Android - take a 200mp photo programmatically

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-camerax

I'm trying to take a photo programmatically with new Samsung's 200mp mode (16320x12240 pixels). The image below shows it selectable on Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra default camera app.

Does Android Camera2 or CameraX support this huge resolution, and if not, what can be used to take such a photo?

[image]

Comment: "Does Android Camera2 or CameraX support this huge resolution" -- that answer could vary by device model and can change over time, so you would be best off testing for yourself. There is no requirement for Samsung (or any manufacturer) to offer all camera options to third parties.